# Was Ant-Man spared because of his location?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, ant-man-and-the-wasp

In *Ant-Man and the Wasp* we saw that Scott just happened to be in the Quantum Realm at the exact moment that

> Thanos snapped his fingers and instantly destroyed half of all life forms in the Universe.

Was Scott saved from this event due to his location? Its not clear if the Quantum Realm does or does not count as part of the Universe.

Comment: Feels like Future Works to me unless there's an interview with someone official

Comment: @Paul, I'm not sure it is Future Works.  We really have no reason to believe this question will necessarily be answered.   All we know is that he wasn't destroyed.  It may be that the Quantum Realm shielded him or that he got lucky.   If you ask me, the likely scenario is that the Quantum Realm allows access to other parallel universes, and in particular allows access to a timeline where the *other half* of Life was preserved instead.  Ta-da!  This explains why all the actors who should be dead are still getting paid and making other MCU movies, etc.

Comment: @ThePopMachine but that would be an explanation. He's in the Quantum Realm has access to other universes and is therefore immune

Comment: @Edlothiad:   Well, it would mean that no one was really destroyed.   That means everyone was immune in some sense, just not in the one timeline we saw.

Comment: @ThePopMachine in hindsight I found a canonical statement, (whether truthful or a lie) so it seems your intuitions were correct, and if you hadn't rebutted the comment I wouldn't have searched for said statement, I therefore thank thee.

Comment: Duplicate of https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/90254/did-this-character-fool-thanos-and-dr-strange

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## It was "Luck."

Responding to Twitter user @pottertardis, the Russo brothers' twitter revealed that Ant-Man survived due to luck.

[image: Russo brothers confirm it was luck]

> Erika: was scott spared by the "luck" of the Infinity Gauntlet draw or was he protected from the snap while he was inside the Quantum Realm?
>
> Russo Brothers: **Luck.**

While I couldn't find the original twitter source (it seems to have been deleted), it is confirmed on numerous sources including [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Spoilers-Did-Ant-Man-survive-Thanos-s-snap-because-he-was-in-the-Quantum-Realm-at-the-time-or-was-it-just-luck/answer/Reed-Kwon) and [ComicBookNews](https://www.cosmicbooknews.com/ant-man-wasp-post-credit-scene-infinity-war).

Comment: I suspect the Russos' comment was what is colloquially known as "a clever lie". They didn't want to tip what it likely a major plot point of Avengers 4 by admitting yes, the quantum realm is in some way outside the reach of Thanos' powers.

Comment: @VBartilucci one is welcome to think so, I would prefer to trust them. Call me a sheep, if it pleases you.

Comment: @VBartilucci “what is colloquially known as "a clever lie"” — is that a colloquialism? Where? Either way, I’m not clear how picking one of the two options provided by the asker is clever.

Comment: It also suggests they were in some way compelled to answer - if they _really_ wanted to give nothing away, the easiest way to do that is to say nothing (or give a GRRM-style "keep watching" response), not to outright lie about the answer then later quietly delete the lie.

Comment: In today's info-heavy world, a choice not to speak is often inferred to be an admission.  In a vacuum of facts, rumor and supposition rush in to fill the void. There's been plenty of examples of producers, directors, stars of fictional works lying boldly to the public for the purpose of keeping a plot point secret.  And I have no problem with that.  It'd be like being legitimately upset with a friend or loved one when they "lie" about the existence of an upcoming surprise party.

Comment: And for the record, "Clever lie" is a Doctor Who reference.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going with **a firm maybe**.

There have been a number of photos from the filming of Avengers 4 that imply that time travel will play a part. There's shots of Chris Evans in the version of his Cap outfit from circa Avengers 1, likewise of Loki seemingly from the past. Similarly, there's shots of what appear to be the heroes (apparently from various eras) wearing devices which are theorized will be used to allow time travel.

[image: Image of time travel devices]

In the tag, Wanda warns Scott to avoid the "time vortices" (He's also told to stay away from the Tardigrades, but the odds of water bears playing a part in A4 is somewhat less likely.)

The Quantum Realm is a bigger plot point that simply for the Ant-Man films. It has been visited (however briefly) by Dr. Strange in the montage where he's given a quick look at how much more is out there.

If one looks at all of this info, it becomes easier to believe that what we saw in the AM&TW tag is indeed a clue to the future plans for A4.

Here's one article that riffs on similar ideas.
[The Wrap - "What is a time vortex?"](https://www.thewrap.com/ant-man-wasp-mid-credits-scene-explained-time-vortex/)

If I may be allowed some complete guessing, recall that the next Marvel film is Captain Marvel, and it takes place decades earlier than the events of Infinity War.  We know that Captain Marvel will be appearing in A4, thanks to the teaser from IW. I have a very strong suspicion that we will be seeing other Avengers from the A4 time period appearing in Captain Marvel, either in its tag, or even more potentially cool, so way far in the background of events that you won't even see them until they point it out in A4 and everybody'll go pull out their Blu-Rays and WOW, there he is...

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "tag" here, I don't understand what the word means in the context you've used.

Comment: "Tag" - post/mid-credits scene, often also used to indicate the short scene after the final commercial break on a TV show, usually containing a throwaway joke, or possibly a teaser to future events.

Comment: Ah ok, I've never seen the word used as such, thanks for that :)

Comment: Here's a scene from The Monkees where Mike explains the term "tag" (Starts at 19:12 if the link doesn't hit the bookmark right) https://youtu.be/LllorP1EgwA?t=19m12s

Comment: I think those devices are used by special effects artists to track their hand movements.

Comment: That would suggest they be needed on both hands, and I've seen photos where they're only worn on one. Also, not that while most of the are affixed with what look like elastic, Ant-Man's appears to be affixed to his suit. If it was to be removed by CGI later, that's a design choice that makes little sense.