# What happened to Doctor Pym's family in the end credit scene?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, ant-man-and-the-wasp

In the end credit scene to *Ant-Man and the Wasp* what happened to Doctor Pym, along with his wife and daughter, when Scott is about to leave the quantum realm? Is Thanos responsible for that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes. They disappeared because of Thanos' snap.**

Someone on Youtube posted a nice montage of the end credits of *Antman and the Wasp* and the scenes from *Avengers: Infinity War* where characters are turned to dust:

In the montage, you can see that the dusting effect is the same.

Comment: If Thanos rule the whole universe, then why quantum realm isn't affected ?

Comment: We don't know since the sequel has not been released yet. Maybe Antman was in the lucky half, maybe  for whatever reason, the Quantum Real is outside the reach of the Infinity Stones.

Comment: i mean scientifically ?

Comment: ah.. then  Infinity Stones is not a Ultimate Weapon in MC universe :-)

Comment: Science in a comic universe is whatever the writers decide. Note that we only have one example of a person in the Quantum Realm with a 1/2 chance of survival that was unaffected. That's not enough to conclude that the Quantum Realm is unaffected by the Stones.

Comment: i'm just saying, :-|

Comment: according to this : https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/191511/was-ant-man-spared-because-of-his-location : Antman survival was luck, not protection because of his location.Additionally, shouldn't it count as duplicate of the link I gave ?

Comment: @dna yes, it does.

Comment: @dna: your link asks about Scott, while this question is about Hank and his family. How could it be a duplicate? Only the question in the comments is a duplicate of the question from your link.

Comment: Video link is dead